# InvokeRepeating not working in unity with .Net 4.6

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I attached the below script to the camera

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sample : MonoBehaviour {

    int i=0;

    void Start () { 
        Debug.Log("This is printed immediately");
        Debug.Log("Called invoke repating ");
        InvokeRepeating("test", 0.0f, 0.5f);
    }

    void test()
    {
        i++;
        Debug.Log("Called invoke repating "+i);
    }

    void Update () {
    }
}
```

this is what i get in my console (it stops and doesn't get invoked repeatedly):

```
This is printed immediately
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Sample:Start() (at Assets/Sample.cs:27)
Called invoke repating 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Sample:Start() (at Assets/Sample.cs:28)
Called invoke repating 1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Sample:test() (at Assets/Sample.cs:36)
```

Does anyone have a clue what is going on... I can't seem to spot any mistake here.

Screenshot - [image]

Comment: According to your log, it is working. It is doing exactly what you have told it to do in your code. What do you mean by not working? What did you expect?

Comment: It has to repeat itself which clearly it isn't .. should continue incrementing but it stops at 1

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your console tab when it stops working? I want to see what's going on.

Comment: added the screenshot as you asked

Comment: Interesting. Is the camera Object deactivated when it stops working? Asking because the screenshot cut that part off.

Comment: Its not. I updated the picture to add that detail as well

Comment: The only time this problem should happen is when you click the PAUSE button then click the START button but that's not the case here according to your screenshot. I suggest you remove that script from the camera and attach it to another GameObject/empty GameObject and see what happens. Also restart Unity and Visual Studio and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked -

Go to **Edit > Project Settings > Time**

`Timescale has to be 1`